# Can every group be extended to ring with idenity

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Can every abelian group converted into ring(by defining multiplication operation) with identity with same order.
We can convert every group G into ring by defining a.b = 0 for all a and b in G. But this ring has no multiplicative identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classification of finitely generated abelian groups implies that the group is a direct sum of copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ and copies of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ for certain natural numbers $n \gt 1$. Endowing these groups with the natural ring structure coordinate-wise gives a non-trivial ring structure.

Comment: What about the non finitely generated case ?